# Need to be able to catch Spring startup exception in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot

I've got a situation where we want to inspect Spring MVC code on startup and throw an exception (thus causing the `ApplicationContext` to to fail) when certain conditions aren't met.

Is there a way to instrument a JUnit test to catch Spring startup (specifically, Spring Boot in most cases) exceptions so that they don't cause a test failure? I basically want to fail the test if the exception *doesn't* happen.

Comment: Will init Spring programmatically with your beans xml description inside a test method, having that method annotated with `@Test(expected=SomeException.class)`, do?

Comment: or even better using @Rule ExpectedException : http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/03/junit-expectedexception-rule-beyond.html

Comment: @Victor Sorokin, I am not sure if that will work or not. I'm currently annotating my unit tests thusly: 

`@RunWIth(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplicationObjects.class) // this one has the controller i want to test
@WebAppConfiguration`

I'm afraid that this inits the Spring app once for all the test methods. I will certainly check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem yesterday. Because the default `SmartContextLoader` classes like `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` and `SpringApplicationContextLoader`, which are pulled in by annotations, fully load the `ApplicationContext`, I couldn't catch any exceptions there.

The solution I came up with--and I'm sure there are much more elegant solutions out there--was to create my own implementation of `SmartContextLoader` that delegated everything to a `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` except the `loadContext` method. There, I did everything except refresh the `WebApplicationContext`. Then, inside my test method, I manually built and ran the `SpringBootApplication` that would hold my test Controller (and invalid configuration).

Thanks to both @viktor-sorokin and @grzesuav for getting me started down a correct path.

Answer (score 9):

In your JUnit test you can start your Spring Boot app programmatically - similar to the `main()` method of your Application class. In such a test you can assert Exceptions as you'd normally do.

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MySpringBootApp.class);
    // Here you can manipulate the app's Environment, Initializers etc.     

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
      springApplication.run();
    }).isInstanceOf(Exception.class);
  }
```